# Ionic + Angular display a card on incomingCall

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have and app, where I store contacts (name + photo + telephone numbers)

This app is not the default dialer app!

I would like to display an ion-card in case one of my contacts call me.

My question: is it possible to do that?
Ionic app able to catch incoming request, and display card? Maybe outside the outside the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

give it a try

[Cordova PhoneCall Trap](https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap)

It only works with Android and not iOS because apps are sandboxed in iOS.